# Issue running Ionic commands in PowerShell

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

When I try to run an ionic command in PowerShell I get an error that says

ionic : The term 'ionic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ionic
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ionic:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Does anyone know how I can fix this?  Do I need to add a path variable to my environment variables?

I have installed node.js successfully and I believe have successfully installed Ionic and Cordova as well with the command "npm install -g ionic cordova"

The output from the "npm install -g ionic" is below

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
ionic@1.3.20 C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic
├── proxy-middleware@0.7.0
├── connect-livereload@0.5.2
├── progress@1.1.7
├── open@0.0.5
├── colors@0.6.2
├── ncp@0.4.2
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── crc@3.2.1
├── async@0.9.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── semver@4.3.1
├── shelljs@0.2.6
├── cross-spawn@0.2.3 (lru-cache@2.5.0)
├── cli-table@0.3.1 (colors@1.0.3)
├── event-stream@3.0.20 (stream-combiner@0.0.4, duplexer@0.1.1, from@0.1.3, map-stream@0.0.5, pause-stream@0.0.11, split
@0.2.10, through@2.3.6)
├── finalhandler@0.2.0 (escape-html@1.0.1, debug@2.0.0)
├── form-data@0.1.4 (mime@1.2.11, combined-stream@0.0.7)
├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── connect@3.1.1 (utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, debug@1.0.4, finalhandler@0.1.0)
├── opbeat-ionic@1.1.3 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, console-log-level@1.0.0, stackman@0.2.2, after-all@2.0.1)
├── npm@2.1.3
├── tiny-lr-fork@0.0.5 (debug@0.7.4, qs@0.5.6, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0.3)
├── serve-static@1.7.1 (escape-html@1.0.1, utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, send@0.10.1)
├── xml2js@0.4.4 (sax@0.6.1, xmlbuilder@2.6.2)
├── unzip@0.1.9 (setimmediate@1.0.2, readable-stream@1.0.33, pullstream@0.4.1, match-stream@0.0.2, binary@0.3.0, fstream
@0.1.31)
├── prompt@0.2.12 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, winston@0.6.2, utile@0.2.1)
├── request@2.51.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, caseless@0.8.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, stringstream@0.0.4,
 tunnel-agent@0.4.0, oauth-sign@0.5.0, node-uuid@1.4.3, qs@2.3.3, mime-types@1.0.2, combined-stream@0.0.7, tough-cookie@
0.12.1, bl@0.9.4, http-signature@0.10.1, form-data@0.2.0, hawk@1.1.1)
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.7 (graceful-fs@3.0.6, lodash@2.4.1, strip-bom@1.0.0, vinyl@0.4.6, mkdirp@0.5.0, through2@0.6.3, glob-st
ream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6)
├── archiver@0.5.1 (lodash@2.4.1, readable-stream@1.1.13, lazystream@0.1.0, zip-stream@0.1.4, file-utils@0.1.5)
└── gulp@3.8.8 (pretty-hrtime@0.2.2, interpret@0.3.10, deprecated@0.0.1, archy@0.0.2, minimist@1.1.1, semver@3.0.1, tild
ify@1.0.0, chalk@0.5.1, orchestrator@0.3.7, gulp-util@3.0.4, liftoff@0.12.1)

Comment: Could you provide the out put for `node -v`, `npm -v`, and `ionic -v`

Comment: The node version is v0.12.2.  The npm version is 2.7.4.  If I try the command ionic -v I get the same error as above.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to install the cli again. Also, can you provide the out put from the CLI. `npm install -g ionic`

Comment: I've added the output from npm install -g ionic to the question.  I'll try to reinstall the cli

Comment: What version of windows do you have?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: thanks @mhartington `npm install -g ionic` fixed the issue for me. probably, a local install was causing the issue

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my mistake.  I was missing a path variable to system32.  Thanks for the help!